# How to adjust the size of current widget class when its size based on another widget class in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am having too many types of buttons in my project, the problem is they all have different sizes. So I decided to create a BaseButtonSize class and then apply its size to the rest. If I want to change the button size, I just simply take the BaseButtonSize.width (or .height) and multiply it with a specific number (you can see it in the code in KButton2 class).

But it doesn't seem to be working. And the traceback returned 5292 lines .-.

So is there any way to fix or better way to do that? When you can adjust the size of the current widget that you taken from another class.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<ViewPort>:
    KButton1:
    KButton2:

<BaseButtonSize>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: Window.width*0.0441,Window.height*0.147

<KButton1>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: button.size
    
    BaseButtonSize:
        id: button

<KButton2>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: button.size
    
    BaseButtonSize:
        id: button
        width: self.width*1.25 # <<<<===== Can not adjust the width (Remove this line will work fine)
""")

class BaseButtonSize(Button):
    pass

class KButton1(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class KButton2(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class ViewPort(BoxLayout):
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    from kivy.app import App
    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return ViewPort()
    
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Which button you're referring in '_If I want to change the **button** size_...' ?

Comment: @ApuCoder The KButton class, in the example, is the KButton2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `width: self.width*1.25` creates an infinite loop. A `width` is assigned to `BaseButtonSize`, then it is adjusted to 1.25 times the `width`, which changes the `width` and triggers the above `kv` rule, which  adjusted the `width` by again multiplying it by 1.25, which triggers the above rule again, ...

You can avoid this infinite loop by using:

```
width: Window.width*0.0441*1.25
```

Or, you can set a `key` in your `kv`, like this:

```
#:set w Window.width*0.0441
```

Then use that elsewhere in the `kv`:

```
<BaseButtonSize>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: w,Window.height*0.147
```

and:

```
BaseButtonSize:
    id: button
    width: w*1.25
```

Both of these approaches eliminate the infinite loop.

Yet another approach (that I think solves all your issues) is to just set a `key` to the `0.0441` value, and use that elsewhere in your `kv`. And set the size in the `KButton` class, allowing the default `size_hint` of `BaseButton` to adjust its size. Here is a modified version of your code that does this:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#: set w_factor 0.0441

<ViewPort>:
    KButton:
        text: '1'
    KButton:
        text: '2'
        width_factor: 1.25

<KButton>:
    width_factor: 1
    size_hint: None,None
    size: Window.width * self.width_factor * w_factor, Window.height*0.147
    text: ''

    BaseButtonSize:
        text: root.text
""")


class BaseButtonSize(Button):
    pass


class KButton(RelativeLayout):
    pass


class ViewPort(BoxLayout):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from kivy.app import App


    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return ViewPort()


    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: That's what I'm avoiding doing... Since every time I want to change the "0.0441" value, I have to do the same for the rest too.

Comment: If you say so, then I suppose there's no other way?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: However, using the `key` does not allow for changing `window` size.

Comment: Hope I can find a way to combine both of your options.

Comment: Another update to my answer.